# Open E-mail in a pop up window from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4

Tags: html, email, browser, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I would like to have a new e-mail window to pop up when I change value on an attribute. 
Does anyone have any suggestion how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple solutions I'd recommend, based on your comment that you added.

1) The easiest might actually be to add a field to the serviceactivity entity called "Email comments" or something, and edit your workflow to include the contents of that field as well as the rest of the content that is currently in the email.

2) You can do what you originally wanted and open up a new email activity, but there are some gotchas:

- If the environment has IFD enabled, the url is going to change between that and a normal CRM deployment, so your javascript will have to account for that.
- The fields that you currently have populated on your workflow (to, from, content) cannot be set from the url. You will have to add some more code to the onLoad event on the email entity to call web services (either through javascript, which is kind of a pain, or setting up custom web services and deploying them to the CRM server) and populate the fields.

`#`1 is going to be a whole lot easier to get pretty much the same end result that you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<INPUT NAME="test" onChange="popup(...)" />
```

where popup would be a javascript function to create the pop-up window

or if this doesn't help, tell us more specifically what type of attributes, language, etc.

Comment: Ok, I will try to be a little bit more specific.
Today I have a workflow that sends an e-mail when I choose "Yes" on the attribute "Send e-mail" on a serviceactivity. The content in the e-mail is information regarding the serviceactivity. The to-field is the customer on the serviceactivity. And from field is the owner of the serviceactivity. The users want often to edit the mail and add some comments. Today it doesn´t work. Because of that we want the entity E-mail to pop up instead so the user can add some comments and after that send the e-mail manually. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague but I suspect you want.

```
<input onchange="window.open('mailto:you@wherever','myEmailWindow');return true">
```

Which may or may not work depending on the users popup-blocking settings.

Comment: Ok, I will try to be a little bit more specific. It is in MCRM 4.0.Today I have a workflow that sends an e-mail when I choose "Yes" on the attribute "Send e-mail" on a serviceactivity. The content in the e-mail is information regarding the serviceactivity. The to-field is the customer on the serviceactivity. And from field is the owner of the serviceactivity. The users want often to edit the mail and add some comments. Today it doesn´t work. Because of that we want the entity E-mail to pop up instead so the user can add some comments and after that send the e-mail manually. Is this possible?

Comment: that isn't specific at all. I don't care what your application is, i need to see the html code you are using to set this "attribute" as you call it. It sounds to me like the email is being from the server. if you want it sent from the clients email program you need to modify your code. Update your question with some *relevant* code or people can't help you.

Comment: Actually for MSCRM 4.0, that is specific. There's no need to see any HTML code in this case. And while Martin should probably have just made this comment the content of his question, it looks like he's a first time user and there's no need to get snippy.